# Indicator/script which writes something on Volume column

Tags: pine-script, volume

Who knows indicator/script which writes something on Volume column?
(no matter what is - I want to use it like basis for my own script % of Candle / Volume ratio) [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6U2i.png)

Tried to find some indicator on tradingview.com: [nothing useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks5wG.png)
I suppose that it's better for this purpose just upgrade some easy script which already indicates something (whatever) on Volume column: [like just only Volume for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9pER.png)